# Bootstrap form layout

Tags: html, css

I just wanted to double check that what I was doing was ok. I am trying to do a layout like so

[image: capture]

So its a horizontal form with a label and text area. However, I wanted to do a list of points under my label which is what I basically have. However, I do not think I have done it in the best way.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="whatDetails" class="col-sm-5 control-label">What
        <ul>
            <li>1.</li>
            <li>2.</li>
            <li>3.</li>
        </ul>
    </label>

    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="whatDetails"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Should I be putting my list within my label element, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: The input has to be different for every li? If that's the case you should put a different label for every li

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean.  The li are just hints for the text input.  I want to move them outside of the label though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be putting my list within my label element,...

No. You should not be putting your list within the `label` element.

As per the specs for `label` here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/label.html#label-constraints

> Permitted contents: phrasing content

and

> the label element may contain at most one descendant input element,
>   button element, select element, or textarea element.

Also, as per the specs for `ul` here:

> Permitted parent elements: Any element that can contain flow elements

---

> ...or is there a better way to achieve this?

Just split your `label` and `ul` into a separate `div` of their own.

***Example:***

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="whatDetails" class="control-label">What</label>
        <ul>
            <li>1.</li>
            <li>2.</li>
            <li>3.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="whatDetails"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```